# For loop answer not matching the correct answer. Difference unidentified between the two loops' working

Tags: r, for-loop, functional-programming

I'm going through coursera R progrmming course. the assignment question im doing is as follows:

Write a function named 'pollutantmean' that calculates the mean of a pollutant (sulfate or nitrate) across a specified list of monitors. The function 'pollutantmean' takes three arguments: 'directory', 'pollutant', and 'id'. Given a vector monitor ID numbers, 'pollutantmean' reads that monitors' particulate matter data from the directory specified in the 'directory' argument and returns the mean of the pollutant across all of the monitors, ignoring any missing values coded as NA.

The dataset for this question is here:
https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/rprog%2Fdata%2Fspecdata.zip

im getting the answer for the first loop as 3.8383 whereas the second gives the correct answer as 4.064. Im unable to find the difference occuring because of subsetting which iv done in first function. my debugging says it should give the same no of rows after subsetting which iv done in function 1 as are appearing in function 2. But something is different.

function 1

```
pollutantmean<-function(directory, pollutant, id=1:332){
  file_list<-list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
  dat<-data.frame()
  mean_select_pol<-c()
  for(i in 1:332){
    dat<- rbind(dat, read.csv(file_list[i]))
  }
  select_pol<-dat[which(dat[,"ID"]==id), ]
  mean_select_pol<-mean(select_pol[, pollutant], na.rm=TRUE)
  mean_select_pol
}
```

function 2

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {
  files <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
  dat <- data.frame()

  for(i in id)
  {
    dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files[i]))
  }

  mean_data <- mean(dat[,pollutant], na.rm = TRUE)
  round(mean_data, digits=3)
}
```

Comment: Yes but i did not get answer to it so i had to post it. im in the learning phase and not getting answers is confidence shattering.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Akrun can you have a look at it and help me in this problem?

Comment: The correct action is to edit your original question for clarity then request that it be reopened.

Comment: what is this line supposed to be doing? `select_pol<-dat[which(dat[,"ID"]==id), ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I haven't been able to get the same answers as you with the data/functions provided regardless of which pollutant I chose. However, I was able to make both functions by correcting a couple issues. Your first is in the line `select_pol<-dat[which(dat[,"ID"]==id), ]` where your `id` takes on multiple values which is incompatible with `==` (which compares only with the first value in `id` hence the warning); You were essentially filtering your whole dataframe down to 1 value of id (I think the first), so the mean would only represent one of the files. Instead you should use `select_pol<-dat[which(dat[,"ID"] %in% id), ]` which I think will do what you intended (`%in%` will compare all the values in id). However, I'm not sure what that line is trying to achieve, the values in your `id` are the same as the `i` in your `for` loop. If `id` is not always `1:332`, then the below will be more efficient since you won't be loading all 332 files then filtering some out

```
pollutantmean<-function(directory, pollutant, id=1:332){
  file_list<-list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
  dat<-data.frame()
  mean_select_pol<-c()
  for(i in id){
    dat<- rbind(dat, read.csv(file_list[i]))
  }
  mean_select_pol<-mean(dat[, pollutant], na.rm=TRUE)
  mean_select_pol
}
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation i had been craving for hours Remi. thanks a ton.